# HTML Blinking text for all browser but in different areas of the body

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get different areas of my html page to blink 'certain' text.  However my code makes all of the text blink.  Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function blinker()
{
    if(document.getElementById("blink"))
    {
        var d = document.getElementById("blink") ;
        d.style.color= (d.style.color=='red'?'white':'red');
        setTimeout('blinker()', 500);
    }
}
</script>

<body bgcolor="#F0F0c0"; onload="blinker();">


<align="Right"><font size="3">Type of Alarm:        <span style="font-     
weight:bold"; div id="blink">Fire</div>
<align="Right"><font size="3"># of Employees Clocked In:<span style="font-   
weight:bold"; div Id="blink">5</div>
```

I only want the words 'Fire' and '5' to blink, but everything blinks.

Comment: U sure it's valid HTML? What's with this "span-div" you invented? `align=right` also interests me.

Comment: Did you think about adding jQueryUi `pulsate` method? https://jqueryui.com/effect/

Comment: Just start over... you have nothing valid here. (your tags are not closed or matched, you have multiple element with the same id, and your js is invalid)

Comment: Then why does it work?  But blinks everything?

Comment: This is strictly for a demo of what we are really trying to do, so using html for the demo works for the time being...I just need to make it work properly.

Comment: Seth, what tags are not closed...this is just a snippet of the entire page.

Comment: body isn't closed, none of your `align` elements are closed, none of your `div` elements are opened, none of your `span` elements are closed, none of your `font` elements are closed, (who still uses those?)

Comment: ... and you're duplicating ids

Comment: Ok, all I am trying to do is make a couple of different texts blink in html...any suggestions? I don't have a problem starting over.

Comment: No reason to down vote everyones answers when they ar trying to help you the best they can with your poor example

Comment: Seth, I was down voting anyone...if it was taken that way, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried to express as better as i can what probably you would try to accomplish, this is actually still not have the expected behaviour but with the snippet you provide you may agree with me is not easy.

I'll give you an example plunkr that you can edit in order to help you:
[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jx2Si5cyA37v9B3wCpk0?p=preview)

```js
function blinker()
{
    if(document.getElementById("blink"))
    {
        var d = document.getElementById("blink") ;
        d.style.color= (d.style.color =='red' ? 'white' : 'red');
        setTimeout(blinker(), 500);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#F0F0c0" onload="blinker()">
  <span style="font-weight:bold; font-size:30px;">Type of Alarm:</span>
  <div id="blink">Fire</div>
  <span style="font-weight:bold; font-size:30px;"># of Employees Clocked In:</span>
  <div id="blink">5</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Stefano...Thank you!  that worked as I wanted it too!

Answer (score -1):

There are several issues in your markup that will need to be addressed. If you were to start again, one way that you can achieve what you are trying to do is with CSS animation.

You define your keyframe colours for 0% and 100% then any element which has a `blink` class will toggle between those colours on an infinite loop like this:

```css
/* -- CSS -- */

@keyframes colours {
 0% {color: #f00;}
100% {color: #fff;}
}
.blink { /*browser prefixes removed for brevity*/
    animation-direction: normal;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-name: colours;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
Type of Alarm:<span class="blink">Fire</span><br />
# of Employees Clocked In:<span class="blink">5</span>
```

Answer (score -2):

You're html code is not valid.

Why don't you use this tag :

```
<blink>
```

Comment: pop_up <blink> doesn't work in most browsers anymore

Comment: Let's add a `marquee` while we're at it!

Answer (score -2):

You can start with this example since we know what you are trying to do but you have invalid mark up:

https://jsfiddle.net/jws5wpfm/

**HTML**

```
<h3>Type of Alarm:
 <span class="blink white">Fire</span>
 <br/>
 # of Employees Clocked In
 <span class="blink">5</span>
</h3>
```

**CSS**

```
.blink {
  color:red
}
.white {
  color: white !important
}
```

**JS**

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    $("span").toggleClass("white");
}, 500);
```